# why is Queue.join() necessary here?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

i am learning python's threading module and have wrote the following code to help myself understand

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
MAX_THREADS = 8
q = Queue()
count = 0

# some i/o process
def io_process(x):
    pass

# process that deals with shared resources
def shared_resource_process(x):
    pass

def func():
    global q, count
    while not q.empty():
        x = q.get()
        io_process(x)
        if lock.acquire():
            shared_resource_process(x)
            print '%s is processing %r' %(threading.currentThread().getName(), x)
            count += 1          
            lock.release()

def main():
    global q
    for i in range(40):
        q.put(i)

    threads = []
    for i in range(MAX_THREADS):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=func))

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    print 'multi-thread done.'
    print count == 40

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the output got stuck like this:

```
Thread-1 is processing 32
Thread-8 is processing 33
Thread-6 is processing 34
Thread-2 is processing 35
Thread-5 is processing 36
Thread-3 is processing 37
Thread-7 is processing 38
Thread-4 is processing 39
```

Note that the prints in main() is not executed which means that some threads are hanging /blocking ?

then i modify the func() method by adding q.task_done():

```
if lock.acquire():
            shared_resource_process(x)
            print '%s is processing %r' %(threading.currentThread().getName(), x)
            count += 1
            q.task_done()  # why is this necessary ?
            lock.release()
```

and now all threads terminates as i expected and get the right output：

```
Thread-6 is processing 36
Thread-4 is processing 37
Thread-3 is processing 38
Thread-7 is processing 39
multi-thread done.
True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i read the doc of Queue.Queue [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and see that task_done() works with queue.join() to make sure all items in queue are processed. but since i did not call queue.join() in main(), why is the task_done() necessary here in func()? What is the cause of thread hanging / blocking when i miss the task_done() code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code. Imagine that you have only one item left in the `Queue` and you'd be using only two threads instead of 8. Then following sequence of events happen:

1. Thread A calls [`q.empty`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.empty) to check if it's empty or not. Since there is one item in the queue result is `False` and loop body is executed.
2. Before thread A calls `q.get` there's a context switch and thread B gets to run.
3. Thread B calls `q.empty`, there's still one item in the queue thus the result is `False` and loop body is executed.
4. Thread B calls [`q.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) without parameters and it immediately returns with the last item from the queue. Then thread B processes the item and exits since `q.empty` returns `True`.
5. Thread A gets to run. Since it already called `q.empty` in step 1 it will call `q.get` next but this will block forever thus your program won't terminate.

You can simulate the above behavior by importing `time` and changing the loop a bit:

```
while not q.empty():
    time.sleep(0.1) # Force context switch
    x = q.get()
```

Note that behavior is the same no matter if `task_done` is called or not.

So why did adding `task_done` help? By default Python 2 will do context switch every 100 interpreter instructions so adding code might have changed the place where context switch occurs. See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225086/how-often-does-python-switch-threads) and [linked PDF](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) for better explanation. On my machine the program didn't hang no matter if `task_done` was there or not so this is just a speculation what caused it to happen for you.

If you want to fix the behavior you could just have infinite loop and pass parameter to `get` instructing it to not block. This causes `get` to eventually  throw `Queue.Empty` exception that you can catch and then break the loop:

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty

def func():
    global q, count
    while True:
        try:
            x = q.get(False)
        except Empty:
            break
        io_process(x)
        if lock.acquire():
            shared_resource_process(x)
            print '%s is processing %r' %(threading.currentThread().getName(), x)
            count += 1
            lock.release()
```