# Python process does not start without a delay

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm working on a complex application involving multiple sockets and threads/processes. For some reason, sometimes this particular process won't run unless a delay was invoked.

Something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def somefunc(self):
        some_thread = Thread(...)  # Some complex processing.
        some_thread.start()

        time.sleep(1)  # Some delay like this is needed. 

        some_process = Process(target=sometarget)
        print('Should start')
        some_process.start()
        print('Should have started')

    def sometarget(self):
        print('It started')

        # Do more complex processing here.
```

This prints out something like:

```
Should start
Should have started
It started  # This gets printed out only if there's a significant delay inserted
```

Not sure if it's just some random occurrence due to how Python schedules jobs underneath, but if I don't put a delay, it doesn't seem to run even after I wait a while.

Comment: *Something like:*? Your code, which is not even close to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can't possibly run because you need `some_process = Process(target=self.sometarget)`. Also, you have two completely irrelevant tags and missing one relevant tag, `multithreading`.  But mostly: if your code can get to execute `time.sleep(1)` statement, it can probably get to execute the process-creation statements. So I don't believe you need the delay (**I didn't**).  I could see a scenario where a delay might be needed -- but in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

When you use threading, you come up against the "global interpreter lock".  The Python interpreter will only allow one thread at a time to be running Python code.  Until you sleep or block for I/O, your main thread will keep running, and your threads will wait.  Python threading is great for I/O-bound loads, but it is nearly useless for CPU-bound loads.  That's why people use multiprocessing instead, where you're actually running a separate interpreter in a separate process.

Comment: This is a great answer in general about the GIL and multithreading but I don't think it really explains what the OP observed and whose code clearly has an error and can't possibly run as is.

Comment: it's not entirely true that the main thread will continue until it hits blocking i/o or sleep.. Threads enable true pre-emptive multi-tasking because they will release the GIL and allow other threads to have it for a while. By default each thread will release after about 5 miliseconds. This is a best effort algorithm that must switch in-between byte codes, so a long running process that amounts to a single bytecode in the interpreter may push the interval slightly longer. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911403/3220135) answer for more)

Answer (score 0):

See my comments to your question and Tim Roberts' answer concerning the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). I could see a scenario where the started thread ("some complex processing") had a lock on the GIL and prevented the main thread from continuing to run and get a chance to start the process-creation statements. But it would probably not have a chance to execute the delay statement (`time.sleep(1)`) either. And if it did, what would that accomplish? If anything, that delay would need to be *in the started thread* so that it would release the GIL and allow the main thread to run. But I found that it was not necessary for that delay to be inserted. I assume that even though the thread is created and "started", the main thread continues to run and gets to create the new process before the new thread actually starts execution.

*This* is a complete, minimal, reproducible example:

```py
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def doWork():
    # 100% CPU-bound
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(100_000_000):
        sum += 1

class MyClass:
    def somefunc(self):
        some_thread = Thread(target=doWork)  # Some complex processing.
        some_thread.start()

        #time.sleep(1)  # Some delay like this is needed.

        some_process = Process(target=self.sometarget) #self.sometarget is needed
        print('Should start')
        some_process.start()
        print('Should have started')

    def sometarget(self):
        print('It started')

# this is required for Windows, which I have:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc = MyClass()
    mc.somefunc()
```

Prints:

```
Should start
Should have started
It started
```